# Concatenation of 2 lists in lambda-calculus

Tags: coq, lambda-calculus, coqide

I have defined the type of a polymorphic list and its constructors, and now trying to
write a fonction that concatenate 2 lists but my function concat does not work

```
Definition listA A :Set :=
    forall T :Set, T -> (A -> T -> T) -> T.
    
Definition pnil (A :Set) : listA A := 
      fun T: Set => fun (x : T ) => fun (c : A -> T -> T) => x.
     
Definition pcons (A :Set): A -> (listA A) -> (listA A):=
    fun (a : A) (q : listA A) => fun T : Set => fun (x : T ) => fun (c : A -> T -> T) => c a (q T x c).
Definition concat (A :Set ) (a b:listA A): listA A :=
    a A b ( pcons A a b).
```

error I get for the function concat

```
In environment
A : Set
a : listeA A
b : listeA A
The term "b" has type "listeA A" while it is expected to have type "A".
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues with your function: first, you use `a` to build some `listA A` and not some `A`, so its first argument should be `listA A` and not `A`. Second, its third argument is also incorrect: in the `cons` case, you simply want to reuse `cons` again, rather than using `b`, so this third argument should be `pcons A` instead of `pcons A a b`.

In the end, you get

```
Definition concat (A :Set) (a b:listA A): listA A :=
    a (listA A) b (pcons A).
```

If you want to test it and convince yourself it does the right thing, you might want to play with

```
Definition tolist (A : Set) (l : listA A) : list A :=
  l (list A) nil cons.

Fixpoint fromlist (A : Set) (l : list A) : listA A :=
  match l with
  | nil => pnil A
  | cons h t => pcons A h (fromlist A t)
  end.
```

that convert from your impredicative encoding to the usual datatype and back.
For instance, you can do

```
Eval compute in tolist nat (concat nat (fromlist nat [0 ; 1]) (fromlist nat [2;3])).
```

and see that the result is indeed `[0;1;2;3]`.